# FluentMigrator creating an initial migration

Tags: fluent-migrator

I've been using in the last 4 months fluent migrator to apply mi migrations up and down, but in those latest days, I realized that all the migrations down were not properly running.
So I decided to have a unit test for migration that performs the `Up` and `Down` and verifies the correctness. My idea was to use SQL Lite in memory and apply the Migration but I realized that I don't have the initial migration since it was created by EF.

I saw that there was an old project from 2019 [here](https://github.com/ritterim/fluentmigrator-generator) that claims to generate the script but when I run it I got the error that other users report in its git issue tab.

Anyone has faced a similar issue and resolved it maybe via Powershell script or so on?

Thanks